# In Hadoop, how to view task's classpath on data node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, classpath

We are running mapreduce jobs with `hadoop jar` command. Our mapreduce code uses hive APIs. We are including hive libraries with `-lbjars` option.

However, hive is installed on all our data nodes so we wanted to check if there's a need to supply the hive jars thru `-libjars` option. I understand that task's classpath may not include the available libraries on datanode, but it only gets the libraries from `-libjars` option, but I just wanted to confirm this.

However, the challenge now is how to check the classpath of a mapreduce task. I tried `ps -ef | grep java` but the output is getting truncated at 4096 bytes(known issue) and `jps -vl` won't even show me the classpath.

Is there any easier method to find out what is the task's classpath is comprised of? Hadoop logs it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can print `CLASSPATH` in the mapper setup and then check it in mapper's log:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   System.out.println(System.getenv("CLASSPATH"));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However , jinfo showed me the classpath of task's JVM.

Comment: BTW, I think `System.getenv("CLASSPATH")` would fetch environment variable.... but here I want the contents of `-classpath` argument to JVM

Answer (score 0):

```
#<java_home>/bin/jinfo <pid>
```

showed me all the information related to task's JVM, including classpath. Look for `java.class.path =` in the output.

Now, how to find out the pid of the task? that's the issue...